# Perfect Image size for the textwidth

Tags: graphics, floats, rstudio

I am exporting some R Studio data manually as a `figure` by the `graphicx` package into my document(`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}`). As I scale my graphics or set their size to `textwidth`, they appear in the wished size but the text is usually stretched and the good image size quality is lost. So I was wondering which pixel width does my textwidth has so that I can export the data in the correct size from R Studio? Thanks!

Comment: pdf is a scalable format so doesn't really have a pixel width, you could work out the number of pixels for a particular print resolution on paper, but on screen you normally view the document at a fairly random scale factor depending on the window size, so the number of screen pixels depends on the viewer's screen. the window size, and other things

Comment: can you not generate a scalable image from R, what image format are you using?

Comment: Also exactly how are you scaling, and as David asks, which format. Note that pdf is not a guarantee that you are dealing with scalable graphics, a pixel based image can easily be converted to pdf, but that does not make it universally scalable (aka vector graphics)

Comment: So far I have worked with the .png image format. I don't suppose it's my screen's fault as my text output is in perfect quality but R's text (legends etc.) seem to be pixeled.

Comment: For scaling I have worked with \textwidth in various sizes and [scale]. But even in [scale=1], which is approx. 1,5 times textwidth, the legendtexts seem pixeld.

Answer (score 1):

When you Export in R Studio, are you choosing Save as PDF?  If so, then in the resulting dialog box keep the PDF Size at the default "(device size)".  If you set it to your A4 paper size then you lose the aspect ratio of the original plot, whereas keeping the size at (device size) preserves aspect ratio.

If instead you have chosen the Save as Image and you wish to resize prior to saving, simply check the box to preserve aspect ratio.  However I find it's easiest to save without adjusting pixel sizes, then head over to LaTeX and play with the `scale` option of the `includegraphics` control sequence until I get the size I want.

Comment: Worked so far with the png format (with checked box for preserve aspect ratio) but tried pdf now and played around a little bit. Works now well for me now - but still I wonder what I did wrong with png...